# Change values in array until no consecutive values

Tags: java, algorithm, array

I have to find an algorithm to solve this question :

> You have an array with n integers in it.  Make an algorithm that changes array so that there are no consecutive expressions in it and returns the amount of changes to be made.
>
> For example in array [1,1,2,2,2] the smallest amount of changes is 2 to get it to [1,3,2,1,2].
>
> [1,2,3,4,5] results output "0", [1,1,1,1,1] results output "2".

I have to change as less values as possible and my code does work as intended. On the other hand, I have the impression that it is not very efficient. What do you think ?
Here it is :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static int untilNoConsecutive(int[] arr) {
    int rounds = 0;
    int arrSize = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize - 2; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {
            arr[i + 1]++;
            if (arr[i + 1] == arr[i + 2])
                arr[i + 1]++;
            rounds++;
        }
    }
    if (arr[arrSize - 2] == arr[arrSize - 1]) {
        arr[arrSize - 1]++;
        rounds++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // for testing purpose
    return rounds;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 };
        int arr2[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int arr3[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        System.out.println(untilNoConsecutive(arr));
        System.out.println(untilNoConsecutive(arr2));
        System.out.println(untilNoConsecutive(arr3));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid repeating the logic outside the loop. Just let the loop run until `i < arrSize - 1`, and add the condition `i + 2 < arrSize` to the inner `if`.

If I'm not mistaken, if the inner `if` condition is true, then the next loop unnecessarily checks the same values again, so I believe you could add `i++` to that inner `if` block.

Finally some style remarks:

- You should always use braces, even on one line blocks.
- I'm not really happy with the variable names:

  - `arr` should probably be called `array` or maybe something that doesn't represent the data format such as `numbers`.
  - `arrSize` could just be called `size` or `len(gth)`.
  - And `rounds` should (based on the task description) be `changes`.

Comment: Okay, so I did what you said. Thank you very much! You were right about the inner if condition, I had not much to change to get this to work.
I'm used to my teacher doing those one line blocks without the braces so that's why... I also changed this! Also thanks for those remarks about variable names. I will try to do so now.